# Cannot install nuget package because the current nuget package manager version is not supported (Entity Framework)

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget, xaf

I upgraded to VS2022 and Dev Express XAF 21.2.4. When I run the Xaf wizard to generate a Winforms Entity Framework solution I get the following error:

[image: Error dialog]

> Cannot install NuGet package because the current NuGet Package Manager
> version is not supported. Please install the latest version of the
> Nuget Package Manager and restart the wizard or add the reference
> manually after the wizard finishes. Package:Entity Framework

From [Nuget help](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) I understand that Nuget comes with VS2022 so I don't understand how I can install the latest version.

[Update]

Typing nuget at the dos prompt or at the developer command prompt for VS 2022 I get

> 'nuget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a conflicting version of nuget somewhere in your path?

Comment: Good point.. I updated the question.

Comment: Looks like you've got an answer on [your DevExpress ticket](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1052004/unable-to-create-xaf-winforms-entity-framework-from-wizard-in-vs2022) with [a link to a workaround](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1053457/core-solution-wizard-cannot-create-a-ef-6-xaf-app-due-to-nuget-package-manager-version).

Comment: Ouch , back from holidays, I had completely forgotten.

Comment: Care to convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a long time

> upgrade vs code if it doesnt work

> https://www.nuget.org/downloads download nuget.exe and manually run nuget restore in that folder